# Haskell: handling cyclic dependencies while tying the knot

Tags: haskell, type-inference, cyclic-dependency, tying-the-knot, st-monad

While writing a programming language that will feature local type inference (i.e. it will be capable of inferring types with the exception of function parameters, like Scala), I've run into a problem with cyclic dependencies.

I perform type-checking/inference by exploring the AST recursively, and lazily mapping each optionally-typed node to a type-checked node. Because the type of any node may depend on the types of other nodes within the AST, I've tied the knot so that I can refer to the types of other nodes while inferring/checking the type of the current node (I keep the typed-AST within the environment of a Reader monad).

This works perfectly well in the typical case, but breaks down with cyclic dependencies, as the program follows the loop endlessly in search of a known type.

The solution to this sort of problem generally (as far as I know) is to maintain a collection of explored nodes, but I cannot think of a referentially-transparent way of doing this while tying the knot, because I do not know in advance the order in which the nodes will be visited/evaluated, as this depends on the graph of their dependencies on one another.

As such, it seems I need to maintain a local, mutable collection of explored nodes. In order to do so, I tried the following:

- Using the State monad, which failed because it *seems* that each sub-computation receives its own copy of the state, so no information about already explored nodes can be shared between different branches of the computation.
- Using the IO monad with IORefs, which precluded me from tying the knot as a result of its strictness.
- Using `unsafePerformIO` with IORefs, which introduced problems with mutations occurring out of order or not at all.
- Using the ST monad with STRefs, which introduced the same problems with strictness as the IO monad.

Finally, I came up with a solution using the ST monad, in which I force lazy evaluation while mapping over the AST using `unsafeInterleaveST`, which works, but feels fragile.

Is there a more idiomatic and/or referentially transparent solution that isn't obscenely lengthy or complicated? I would have included a code sample, but my simplest formulation of this problem is ~250 lines.

Comment: I don't know of any real-world type checker which uses knot tying. I don't think it's going to get you far. A state of constraints/metavariables is the usual implementation, or bidirectional type checking for simple cases.

Comment: @András-Kovács I've never written a compiler before, but a knot tying implementation appears to me to be a suitable solution by virtue of the fact that it works. I'm curious to read about those other methods you mentioned, thanks for posting!

Comment: To expand on the 'constraint' solution: when you encounter a mutual recursive block, e.g. `let x = y; y = x in ..`, you can assign a fresh type to all the variables; `x : t0; y : t1` and check each binding in sequence. When inferring the type of `x = y`, you emit an equality constraint `t0 ~ t1` and continue (without recursing to infer the type of `y`, since it is part of the same mutual block); then you infer `y = x` in the same manner by emitting the constraint `t1 ~ t0`. At the end, you must solve the (trivial) unification problem `t0 ~ t1 /\ t1 ~ t0`; one solutions is `t0 -> t0; t1 -> t0`.

Comment: As far as a knot tying implementation goes, I've just discovered `Control.Monad.ST.Lazy`, which obviates the need for `unsafeInterleaveST` and works like a charm :)